# difference in how to return a promise?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I was working on an app this morning and found something interesting...wondering if anyone can explain the behavior I'm seeing.

I'm building a reporting suite that requires some prerequisites be loaded before the reports can run. I need my data from Firebase, and I also need to dynamically load some Handlebars templates to display that data. Because there are several report pages, I made the data and template loading operate via deferred objects. So in my `reports.js` file, I have something like this:

```
var report = {};

(function($) {

    report = {
        prefetchData : function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(d) {
                // get data
                d.resolve();
            }).promise();
        },

        prefetchTemplates : function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(d) {
                var templates = $.map($("[data-template]"), function(o) {
                        return $(o).data('template');
                    }),
                    getTemplate = function(name) {
                        $.get(name, function(data) {
                            report.templates[name] = data;
                        });
                    },
                    toDownload = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < templates.lenght; i++) {
                    toDownload.push(getTemplate(templates[i]));
                }

                $.when.apply($, toDownload).done(function() {
                    d.resolve();
                }).fail(function() {
                    d.reject();
                });
            }).promise();
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

My report page script looks like this:

```
var report = report || {};

(function($) {

    $.when(
        report.prefetchData(),
        report.prefetchTemplates()
    ).done(function() {
        // load the charts, etc.
    });

})(jQuery);
```

What I discovered was that the charts would start to render before the template had been downloaded, especially if I was running the pages in a slower environment. So I changed the `prefetchTemplates` function to this:

```
prefetchTemplates : function() {
    var d = $.Deferred(),
        templates = $.map($("[data-template]"), function(o) {
            return $(o).data('template');
        }),
        getTemplate = function(name) {
            $.get(name, function(data) {
                report.templates[name] = data;
            });
        },
        toDownload = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < templates.lenght; i++) {
        toDownload.push(getTemplate(templates[i]));
    }

    $.when.apply($, toDownload).done(function() {
        d.resolve();
    }).fail(function() {
        d.reject();
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

Now, even in the slowest of environments, my templates are always downloaded before the charts begin to render, which is the behavior I want. So my question is: what's the difference between `return $.Deferred(function(d) {...}).promise();` and `var d = $.Deferred(); ... return d.promise();`? Put another way, if the main `.done()` method won't fire until all returned promises have resolved, why would it make a difference if my function is wrapped inside a deferred callback vs. executing "normally"? Is it just a timing thing, or does the deferred object work differently depending on how it's created?

Comment: I think you forgot to return the promise from `getTemplate`, might be a copy-paste error, because that would have made the $.when resolve instantly rather than when it has data.

Comment: But the `getTemplate` function isn't meant to resolve the promise; it's just meant to populate the `report.templates` object. The resolution should happen in the `$.when()` function once all the templates have been stored. Unless I'm completely missing what you're saying?

Comment: If you don't return from getTemplate, the $.when is useless because if it isn't given promises to attach to, it'l just resolve instantly. Your current code basically resolves `d` almost immediately.

Comment: Okay, I think I see the problem. (Turns out my "solution" actually doesn't work.) How do I modify the `getTemplate` function so that I'm still waiting on the results of `n` number of `$.get()` statements? Just return `d`?

Comment: just add `return `, like this: `return $.get(...);`

Comment: Well poop. Yeah, that'd do it. Looks like that fixed my issue for real this time. Want to put your comment as the answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "working" solution is just coincidentally working, and not actually doing what you think it is doing.

When you loop over your data and populate the `toDownload` array, you're populating it with the value `undefined` because your `getTemplate` function doesn't return anything. You should have it return a promise.

```
getTemplate = function(name) {
    return $.get(name, function(data) {
        report.templates[name] = data;
    });
},
```

As far as

```
return $.Deferred(function(d) {...}).promise();
```

vs

```
var d = $.Deferred(); ... return d.promise();
```

They are exactly the same and should not have performed any differently. I would blame coincidence or convenient timing.